# Classification error per fold of cross validation for comparing algorithms

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, classification, decision-tree, cross-validation

I was wondering whether, if you were to run cross-validation on, for example, a neural network versus a decision tree, computing the classification error per fold is a good and valid way to compare these to algorithms?

Comment: Since it's a classification problem why you don't use the final accuracy as a way to compare the algorithms ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut what exactly do you mean by final accuracy? You mean the accuracy of classification over the test set?